# Which Layer does API access sit in?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I ma trying to wrap my head round the Django Framework and mapping it out on an architecture diagram. I am struggling to understand where the API calls are place (Model or View) and would like some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of API calls as views that strictly return data.